# Getting no records when making Ajax request

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to make a request to a server but im getting no records. When i run the code I am getting no error messages so I assume my code is working but when the callback function is executed on store load I just get a blank message.

```
var proxy = Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.create({
           type:'ajax',
           url:loginHostUri,
           method:'POST',
           headers:{
               'Accept':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           },
           extraParams:{
               grant_type:'password',
               username:username,
               password:psswd,
               client_id: consumerKey,
               client_secret: consumerSecret
           },
           reader:{
               type:'json',
               root:''
           }
       });

       var store = Ext.getStore('instance');
       store.setProxy(proxy);
       store.load({
           callback:function(records,operation,success){
               Ext.Msg.alert('INFO',records,Ext.emptyFn);
           },
           scope:this
       });
```

The message is just blank but I know the Json response looks like this:

```
  {
           "":{
               "id":"2332123",
               "issued_at":"090342",
              " instance_url":"instance",
               "signature":"sig",
               "access_token":"access"
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

define a fields or a model for the store

```
store.setFields({name: 'id', name: 'issued_id' ...});(put this before store.load())
```

Try that and console.log(records) under callback and reply back what you get...

Comment: I have already defined a model for this store. Do I still need to call store.setFields?